# get string in url (web scraping)

Tags: xml, r, httr

I'm not familiar with web scraping although I've managed to get some contents in few ocasions. However, this time although my problem looks simple I can't get a string containing the symbol, name and market in a web page. That is, I'd like to get the string "Merck KGaA (MRK.DE)
-XETRA" in the url. I've tried the following code which returns few tables but I can't get the piece I'm looking for:

```
url <- 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=MRK.DE&ql=0'
require(httr)
require(XML)
table <- readHTMLTable(content(GET(url)),header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient script here, but it'll definitely work:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("h2") %>%
  extract2(3) %>%
  as('character') %>%
  str_replace('<h2>', '') %>%
  str_replace('</h2>', '')

[1] "Merck KGaA (MRK.DE)"
```

Comment: many thanks for your help. Do you know why the string is not captured by a more direct call such as the one I tried? On one hand, I would like to either use base R or some standard packages such as `XML` or  `httr`/`RCurl` if possible. On the other hand, the simpler the code the better.

Comment: `rvest` is actually a package recently released by Hadley to mirror Beautiful Soup from Python.  I have found it to be the most intuitive without a strong working knowledge of HTML.  In your example, `readHTMLTable` will only scrape table data from the given page and it doesn't look like "Merck..." sits within a table.

Comment: You can make it a bit simpler: `html(url) %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text() %>% .[[3]]`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @hadley!  I definitely like your answer better.  I was still tinkering with your package when I came across the question.  As always, thanks for making my life easier. :)